# In MIPS I need programs that will calculate exponents using repeated addition, and one that can solve division using repeated subtraction

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

Code for Exponents:

```
 .data
    a: .word 5 #base
    B: .word 6 # power
    
.globl main
main:
    lw $s0, a # $s0 = a
    lw $s1, B # $s0 = B
    li $s3, 1 # i = 1
    li $s4, 1 # j = 1
    move $t0, $s0 # answer = base
    move $s1, $t0 # increment = base

    
For1: 
    blt $s1, $s3, Exit #for(i=1; i < B; i++)
    addi $s3, $s3, 1 #i++
    li $s4, 1 # resets j to 1
    move $t0, $t1
    j For2
    
For2:
    blt $s0, $s4, For1 #for(j=1; j <a; j++)
    add $t0, $t0, $t1
    addi $s4, $s4, 1
    j For2

Exit:
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Code for Division:

```
.data
    a: .word 1562
    B: .word 7
    space: .asciiz "\n"
.globl main     
main:
    lw $s0, a
    lw $s1, B
    add $t1, $zero, $s0 #make copy of first integer value in $s0
    add $t2, $zero, $s1 #make copy of second integer value in $s1
    add $t0, $zero, $zero #make $t0 the counter
    
div_loop:
    sle $t3, $t2, $t1 #checks if equal
    beq $t3, $zero, end_divis
    
    sub $t1, $t1, $t2
    addi $t0, 1
    j div_loop
    
end_divis:
    move $s5, $t0
    move $s6, $t1
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s5
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s6
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I modeled both of these off of Java programs i wrote that perform the same functions but i am getting a "program is finished running (dropped off bottom) error on them both as well as a Mars message saying "Go: execution terminated by null instruction"

I the exponents program to print the answer and the division program to print both the quotient and the remainder.

EDIT: Added in termination code, when ran in Step mode i errors out with the same error immediately.

I am very new to Assembly so any help would be incredible.

Thanks

EDIT2:  This is the java code I am attempting to translate from
EDIT3:  Division Code is now functioning properly
java code for exponents:

```
public class exponentLoop {
    public static final int BASE = 5;
    public static final int POWER = 6;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int answer = BASE;
        int increment = BASE;
        for(int i = 1; i < POWER; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < BASE; j++)
            {
                answer += increment;
            }
            increment = answer;
        }
        System.out.println(answer);

    }

}
```

Java code for division

```
public class divLoopTest {

    public static final int F = 1562;
    public static final int G = 7;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 0;
        int rest = F;
        while(rest >= G)
        {
            rest = rest - G;
            result ++;
        }
        System.out.println("result = "+result);
        System.out.println("remainder = "+rest);

    }

}
```

Comment: The error message clearly states the problem. Your code has no ending. You need an exit syscall.

Comment: i just added an exit syscall using
`li $v0, 10
syscall`

and the result is the same

Comment: That is unlikely. [edit] your question with the updated code. Make sure you are running the new version. Also use your simulator to single step the code and verify it gets to the exit call.

Comment: updated.  It doesnt make it past the first step.  As in when i click the step function is terminates with the same error.

Comment: You should switch back to `.text` after your data.

Comment: @Jester, missing `.text` is likely the real problem with the whole program not working.  I don't know why the assemblers don't give at least a warning for that, but meanwhile, MARS, for example, won't let you put `.word` in code...

Comment: adding the `.text` gave me an output, but the output is not what it should be.  Thank you, i'm going to begin tweaking it to try and get the proper output

Answer (score 0):

In the first program:

- you don't do anything interesting to provide a value for `$t1`.
- every time you execute the for-j loop, you reset `$t0` to the (uninitialized) `$t1`.  Therefore the outer loop, for-i, has none of the desired effect since the inner loop simply starts over (nothing is being accumulated by iterations of the for-i loop, and so the result is as if you'd only done the for-j loop once)
- your loop test comparisons are off by 1, as you are exiting the for-loops on less-than condition, but: your exit condition should be the opposite of the Java stay-in condition, which is `<` — and the opposite of `<` is `>=`, but since you reversed the operands to `blt` from the Java code that would then require `<=`.

So, assuming your Java code works, you need to look over your variables from the Java and the mappings in assembly.  And try to translate the Java to assembly as literally as possible — don't take short cuts, optimizations, or other during translation.

Otherwise, you're pretty close, and the approach of making a working Java (or preferably C) program and translating that (as literally as possible) is a good approach.

Comment: The java code does work, thank you for these pointers i will try to translate better

Comment: There are times when we want the same logical operation but with operands reversed.   Then there are other times when we want the opposite or negation of the logical operation.  (And sometimes we need both..)
In the former case the "operand swap opposite" of `<` is `>`, meaning `a < b` is the same as `b > a`.  But if you want the negation of the condition, the "negating opposite" of `<` is `>=`, meaning `!(a <b)` is the same as `a >= b`  Hope you can see the difference of how the `=` moves or doesn't move depending on whether we are merely swapping operands or logically negating a condition.

Comment: I understand the logic behind this yes, but I am still confused where I need to implement what.  Also, I fixed where I was resetting `$t0` to the uninitialized `$t1`. I believe you were referring to `move $t0, $t1`  I just reversed the two arguments, and the output I get is way higher than the expected 233280 vs the 15625 that i should be getting and im going to assume its because of the loop comparison issue.  I'm just not sure of what to change

Comment: The division code is now working properly, i only need to fix the multiplication loop now

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you, i changed the `blt` to `ble` and it works

Comment: Super, glad to hear!